# DER Encode BCECPublicKey

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keytool, pki, der

I'm trying to Der encode a public key, and use it with an external service.

When I get the encoded `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey` and send it to the external service, it responds with "ECDSA certificates with unnamed curves are unsupported". (I'm calling `publicKey.getEncoding()` to get the encoded key)

```
publicKey.getFormat();
// "X.509"
publicKey.getAlgorithm();
// "ECDH"
publicKey.getQ().curve.getClass().name;
// "org.bouncycastle.math.ec.custom.sec.SecP256R1Curve"
```

I'm not really sure how to debug from here. I tried saving the raw encoded bytes
 to a file and inspecting the cert with openssl without success:

```
> openssl x509 -in test.der -inform der -text -noout
unable to load certificate
62375:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1344:
62375:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:848:
62375:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:768:Field=serialNumber, Type=X509_CINF
62375:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:768:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Find out the what formats and values the external service expects, using something other than trial and error.

Comment: I don't believe you can use `openssl x509` to print a key. `openssl x509` is used for certificates, and not keys. Maybe you should use Peter Gutmann's `dumpasn1` to print what you have and add it to the question. But my feeling is, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow should not be used for questions on how to use tools like `keytool` or `openssl`. And it can't help with unknown [web?] services rejecting parameters.

Comment: The *"ECDSA certificates with unnamed curves are unsupported"* probably indicates you used domain parameters instead of a named curve like `secp256r1`. Maybe you should instruct Bouncy Castle to use the named curve instead of domain parameters. Here's the problem in the context of OpenSSL programming, but I don't know the BC equivalent: [Elliptic Curve Cryptography | Named Curves](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography#Named_Curves).

Comment: (@jww) `openssl x509` takes a cert but `openssl pkey -pubin` (or before 1.0.0 `openssl ec -pubin`) (here either with `-noout -text`) takes what JCE calls X.509 format which is SubjectPublicKeyInfo. markw: how did you generate this key, or if you read it in from something, what format is that something and how was _it_ generated? Also, did you (or do you want to) send just the pubkey, or a certificate? A _cert_ can be specifically ECDSA, but a key can't distinguish ECDSA from other EC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(publicKey, X509EncodedKeySpec.class);
return keySpec.getEncoded();
```

Comment: And... I found out that it seems that the result of `BCECPublicKey.getEncoded()` is exactly the DER format, no need for additional convertion.